# Is MVC Contrib Grid part of Asp.Net MVC 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

Is it part of Asp.Net MVC 2.0. If not then does Asp.Net MVC 2.0 ship with in built GridView support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it part of Asp.Net MVC 2.0.

No. MvcContrib grid is not a part of MVC 2.

> If not then does Asp.Net 2.0 ship with
>   in built GridView support?

Yes. The [Asp.Net Gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(VS.80).aspx) was introduced with .Net Framework 2.0

Comment: Sorry, I meant Asp.Net MVC 2.0. Does it have in built GridView?

Comment: I am afraid not. But there a several available. There are jQuery implementations, and Telerik has one.

Comment: But why cant you use MvcContrib?

Comment: Grid is such a basic requirement for any basic project that I thought it should be available out of the box in Asp.Net MVC

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [jQuery grid](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) with MVC .

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC 2 does not have a built in GridView helper.  But there are several that can be used, such as the [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc-beta) open source mvc controls, the MvcContrib, and several jQuery options (such as jqgrid).  Or you could just render the grid yourself. Or build your own helper.